# How can I run html code from another page (eg having a single html file for my <head> and referencing that)

Tags: html

Question is in the title. I have a load of code that needs to be mimicked on every page in my website, and want to centralise it into one document and have a single command to call it instead of doing this. It came to light as a problem recently as I needed to change something and now I need to double check to make sure it is changed throughout the project, which I can only assume will involve me missing at least one page.

I originally was doing this locally using php `include "a_document.html";` but I need something that uses either html or js.

I have tried using an `<object>` but that doesn't work as you can't load an object inside the `<head>`. Apparently there used to be an include tag for html but that has been depreciated it seems?

Comment: You can embed html in js script in head,  and then redner it when page loads.

Comment: Use a template engine that supports fragments. Manipulating the  `head` with Javascript is going to cause you alot more headache than what you have now.

Comment: There is no direct way to do this in HTML. You could have some JavaScript inject your common HTML into each page, but that will not have the same effect as a PHP include would (especially if your users have JS disabled). You might look into a static site generator such as eleventy, if you're targeting a static (HTML + JS) site without a server component.